# Python interpreter exiting for loops before iteration is complete:

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, recursion

I am building a Python script to select and open files from an arbitrary set of subdirectories. To do this I am building a function with a for loop to make a list of all the files within a directory, and another list of all the sub-directories within that directory. Then another for loop changes to each of the subdirectories by calling the same function recursively. I have stepped through this function repeatedly in debug mode and watched each variable very carefully as it changes step by step.

I am totally bewildered because each loop functions for a little bit, but then it quits without finishing. Usually in programming things work completely or not at all, but very rarely do they function only halfway. Both loops do this and when the second call to the function quits it does not return to the first call to finish its second loop, but exits from all calls to the function completely. Here is the code, I would greatly appreciate your help:

```
def descend(directory, depth, dive=-1): # dive=-1 before we have touched the surface 
    global choices                      # list of files to be chosen from later  
    os.chdir(directory)                 # change to target directory 
    dirlist = []                        # empty the list of directories within the directory   
    baseList = os.listdir(directory)    # list of all files and directories

    if dive < depth:                    # depth corresponds to the levels of sub-directories to be searched
        dive += 1                       # effectively starts at 0

        fileIndex=0                     # index as we step through the baseList
        for x in baseList:              # why doesn't this loop complete?
            if os.path.isfile(x) == True:   # if it's a regular file
                path = directory + '/' + baseList.pop(fileIndex)    # create its full path
                choices.append(path)                                # and add that to our list of choices
            elif os.path.isdir(x) == True:                  # if it's a directory
                dirlist.append(baseList.pop(fileIndex))     # add to list of directories to recursively search
            fileIndex += 1      # add 1 to the file index

        for x in dirlist:       # for each item in the list of directories
            nextdir = directory + '/' + dirlist.pop()   # make a variable of its full path
            descend(nextdir, depth, dive)               # pass that back to this function and repeat
```

I have even tried silly solutions like adding `if len(baseList) != 0: continue` to the bottom of the loops that shouldn't need to be told twice but this does not help either of them. I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Don't delete elements from a list that you're iterating over. I have no clue why you're using `pop` here, but I think the fix should be as simple as replacing that with `baseList[fileIndex]` (or `x`).

Comment: @Aves You just want to get `baseList[fileIndex]`, not remove it from the list as the same time with `baseList.pop(fileIndex)`. But anyway, you don't need to manage this `fileIndex`: just do `path = directory + '/' + x`

Comment: Well, that was fast...I thought I had it that way to begin with and needed to change it to solve a problem, but now I replaced the .pop() functions with x and it seems to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm going to answer my own question here because I was curious and did some more research, and it is too long for a comment. Maybe this will help clarify it for someone else. After figuring out what was going on through playing around with IDLE, I found this in Pydoc:

Note: There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the
  loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, e.g. lists).  An
  internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next,
  and this is incremented on each iteration.  When this counter has
  reached the length of the sequence the loop terminates.  This means
  that if the suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the
  sequence, the next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of
  the current item which has already been treated).  Likewise, if the
  suite inserts an item in the sequence before the current item, the
  current item will be treated again the next time through the loop.
  This can lead to nasty bugs that can be avoided by making a
  temporary copy using a slice of the whole sequence, e.g.,

```
 for x in a[:]:
     if x < 0: a.remove(x)
```

Input and Output from my IDLE experiment:

```
>>> baselist=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> listeven=[]
>>> listodd=[]
>>> index=0
>>> for x in baselist:
        print('baselist is ', baselist)
        print('listeven is ', listeven)
        print('listodd is ', listodd)
        print('x is ', x)
        print('index is ', index)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print('appending ', x, ' to listeven by popping from baselist')
            listeven.append(baselist.pop(index))
        else:
            print('appending ', x, ' to listodd by popping from baselist')
            listodd.append(baselist.pop(index))
        index += 1

baselist is  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
listeven is  []
listodd is  []
x is  0
index is  0
appending  0  to listeven by popping from baselist
baselist is  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
listeven is  [0]
listodd is  []
x is  2
index is  1
appending  2  to listeven by popping from baselist
baselist is  [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
listeven is  [0, 2]
listodd is  []
x is  4
index is  2
appending  4  to listeven by popping from baselist
baselist is  [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
listeven is  [0, 2, 4]
listodd is  []
x is  6
index is  3
appending  6  to listeven by popping from baselist
baselist is  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9]
listeven is  [0, 2, 4, 6]
listodd is  []
x is  8
index is  4
appending  8  to listeven by popping from baselist
>>> baselist
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Removing items from a list in mid-loop causes the interpreter to think it has finished iterating early because its hidden internal index tells it that the next index is out of range, meaning some values are skipped!

Now this function looks like:

```
def descend(directory, depth, dive=-1): 
global files
os.chdir(directory)
subBranches = []
baseList = os.listdir(directory)
if dive < depth:
    dive += 1
    for x in baseList:
        if os.path.isfile(x) == True:
            path = directory + '/' + x
            files.append(path)
        elif os.path.isdir(x) == True:
            subBranches.append(x)
    for x in subBranches:
        nextdir = directory + '/' + x
        descend(nextdir, depth, dive)
```